# Direction: rtl, Date alignment issue

Tags: html, css, alignment, arabic, direction

When I use `direction:rtl` for the Arabic view, the details on the date are not in showing incorrect order.
E.g. in `ltr` it's showing like `03 February 2016` but in `rtl` it's wrongly aligned as `February 2016 03`.

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="direction:rtl;">
  03 February 2016
</div>
```

Is there any way to rectify it. Or it's just the natural way of showing date in the Arabic view?

Comment: Can someone explain where does such behaviour comes from? Why year is being put in the middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your next question:

```html
  <div style="float:left; direction:rtl;">
    &#x202b;03 February &#x202c;2016
  </div>
```

Comment: In My case when I shift layout in Arabic(RTL) so following property is working for Date format:

float:left;
direction:ltr;

Answer (score 2):

[You can change this behavior](https://jsfiddle.net/e29dotoj/2/) by adding Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING' (U+202A) and ending it by [POP](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Terminating_Explicit_Directional_Embeddings_and_Overrides).

```
<div style="direction:rtl;">
&#x202a;03 February 2016&#x202c;
</div>
```

Comment: But how can I get an order "2016 February  03".?

Answer (score 2):

`&#x202b;03 February &#x202c;2016` solution works good for chrome. But it changes the output as 'mm ddyyyy' in firefox and IE.

Following works consistently in chrome, firefox and IE.

```html
<div style="float:left; direction:rtl;">
    15 &#x202b;May&#x202c; 2017
</div>
```

If you are working with angular js and want to apply the solution in date formatter then, you can write as below:

```
<div style="float:left; direction:rtl;">
   {{ 1463725737789 | date: 'dd &#x202b;MMM&#x202c; yyyy'}}
</div>
```

Input in angular expression should be valid javascript date object. Given input '1463725737789' is time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

this is common, if you use direction RTl you can view mirror image of text, so if you use arabic data it shows perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [**dir**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) attribute to assign rtl directionality. It makes your code much cleaner and easy to read.

```css
div[dir='rtl'] {
  float: left;
}


/*Only supported in Firefox*/
:dir(rtl) {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl">
  15 &#8235;January&#8236; 2020
</div>
```